# Structured Streaming spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference not handling schema changes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
sparkSession.config("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", true).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.readStream().parquet("file:/files-to-process");

StreamingQuery streamingQuery =
dataset.writeStream().option("checkpointLocation", "file:/checkpoint-location")
.outputMode(Append()).start("file:/save-parquet-files");

streamingQuery.awaitTermination();
```

After streaming query started If there's a schema changes on new paruet files under files-to-process directory. Structured Streaming not writing new schema changes. Is it possible to handle these schema changes in Structured Streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help from spark doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets

> Partition discovery does occur when subdirectories that are named
> /key=value/ are present and listing will automatically recurse into
> these directories. If these columns appear in the user-provided
> schema, they will be filled in by Spark based on the path of the file
> being read. The directories that make up the partitioning scheme must
> be present when the query starts and must remain static. For example,
> it is okay to add /data/year=2016/ when /data/year=2015/ was present,
> but it is invalid to change the partitioning column (i.e. by creating
> the directory /data/date=2016-04-17/)